# ElasticSearch, Multiple Indices search

Tags: elasticsearch

Can anyone help me for below use case:

I want to have 3 schools, each school has multiple students, so i want to be able to search the student names, but the search result should tell me that the text that I searched belongs to which school, here is what i am thinking would be the solution with having a problem:

I should have an index for each school and then using multi match to match the entered text against all the indexes, **but the problem is that i want to know each matched result is belong to which index?** please if there is a better solution for the use case or how can i solve the mentioned problem. Thank you All..

BR

Answer (score 0, accepted):

when you run a search you get back a response that contains this;

```
"hits" : [
      {
        "_index" : ".async-search",
        "_type" : "_doc",
        "_id" : "CdT9fKXfQpOEIPuZazz0BA",
        "_score" : 1.0,
        "_source" : {
```

so you can use that `_index` value there to determine things.

ps - it's Elasticsearch, not ElasticSearch :)

Comment: Thanks a lot, it should be accepted answer, appreciated, and regarding the "ElasticSearch", it's kinda became a habit, you know naming convention stuff in programming hahaha thanks again.